# How do I calculate the signature an AWS S3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use this example to calculate an AWS4 signature for an s3 upload -
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

```
var exampleSecretKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
var exampleBase64EncodedPolicy = "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";

var expectedValue = "8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e";

var awsSignature = AWS4Signer.ComputeSignature("AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE", exampleSecretKey, "us-east-1", new DateTime(2015, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), "s3", "", exampleBase64EncodedPolicy);
```

I'm using the values provided in the example but not getting the expected value from the ComputeSignature method. I suspect it's because I'm passing in an empty string for the "signedheaders" argument (if so then what should this be?). Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Which library and language do you use? Can you provide a code snippet you use to initiate the upload?

Comment: That was c# using the AWS S3 nuget package. I was just trying to use the examples to generate the same signature in the tutorial - which I've now worked out how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Never managed to get it working with AWS4Signer but I have managed to do it manually.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class S3UploadSignature
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the X-Amz-Signature parameter for an S3 upload via the browser 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="base64EncodedPolicy">The upload policy JSON string encoded as base 64</param>
    /// <param name="awsSecretKey">The AWS secret identity key</param>
    /// <param name="date">The date the request was signed (yyyyMMdd)</param>
    /// <param name="regionName">The AWS region the bucket sits in e.g. us-east-1</param>
    /// <param name="serviceName">The AWS service name e.g. s3</param>
    public static string Create(string base64EncodedPolicy, string awsSecretKey, string date, string regionName, string serviceName)
    {
        var signatureKey = CalculteSignatureKey(awsSecretKey, date, regionName, serviceName);
        return ToBase16String(HmacSha256(base64EncodedPolicy, signatureKey));
    }

    private static string ToBase16String(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);

        foreach (var b in bytes)
            result.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

        return result.ToString();
    }

    private static byte[] HmacSha256(string data, byte[] key)
    {
        return new HMACSHA256(key).ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
    }

    private static byte[] CalculteSignatureKey(string key, string dateStamp, string regionName, string serviceName)
    {
        var secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
        var date = HmacSha256(dateStamp, secret);
        var region = HmacSha256(regionName, date);
        var service = HmacSha256(serviceName, region);
        var signing = HmacSha256("aws4_request", service);

        return signing;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used the AWS4Signer, but reading the docs (or trying to... they seemed to comply perfectly with the Java standard that requires library documentation contain very little helpful content) this thing looks like it's intended for signing HTTP requests, not `POST` policy documents.  For example, the "signed headers" you mentioned isn't a relevant concept for a form-based uploads, since only the policy document itself is actually signed, not the headers.  It's different than essentially any other request you'd make to S3 or any other AWS service in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
import com.amazonaws.util.BinaryUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AwsTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String stringToSign = getStringToSign("<policy_json>");
        Assert.assertEquals("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", stringToSign);

        String signature = getSignature(stringToSign, "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY", "20151229", "us-east-1", "s3");
        Assert.assertEquals("8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e", signature);
    }

    private static String getStringToSign(String policy) throws Exception {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(policy.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    private static String getSignature(String stringToSign, String secretAccessKey, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
        byte[] signingKey = getSignatureKey(secretAccessKey, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName);
        return BinaryUtils.toHex(HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signingKey));
    }


    private static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    }

    private static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
        byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
        byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
        byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
        byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
        return kSigning;
    }
}
```